# SplitContainer splitter in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, splitter

i am using a split container. For some reason, the splitter looks like this:
[image]

It is very hard to see. It is the faint 2 lines in the middle of the two black lines. How do i fix this issue and add a filling between the two lines? I am using Fixed Single as my border style.

Comment: that changes the whole border, i only need the splitter changed

Comment: Then change the color of the splitter and not the border.

Comment: Have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.splitterwidth.aspx?

Comment: Ok, i am using a split container control...the splitter is a part of the control

Comment: @Patrick yes, that is why there is space in between the two lines..i tried that, but it did not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing the backcolor, but if using the designer, then also go into Panel1 and Panel2 and change those respective backcolors to the colors you want.

Also, their is a SplitterWidth property that can adjust the overall size of the splitter handle.

Comment: thanks, all i had to do was change the back colors of the panels and set a different color in the splitter background...

Comment: Also, why when i click on it to move, it does not move in real time...it does not move until you release the left click???

Comment: @EliteGamer That's just the way the split container works.  You should see a dithered bar moving with the cursor, but other than that, once you mouse up and let go, then the sub panels will resize themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the split container's anchors are set properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use backcolor to change the color.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx