# How can I make the splitter visible on a SplitPanel without creating a border

Tags: c#, splitcontainer

Using 3 nested [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx)s in my Windows Forms Application. When encountered the same problem that other have with the splitter bar being the same color as the surrounding panels. The [common solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11530023/1111886) seems to be to change the [BackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx) but when nesting this results in an unsightly border around the nested panels:

[image: Form with borders around the containers in the SplitContainer]

I've also people [suggesting the use](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/8c54057c-e980-4064-a702-7f0d18310a54) of the Fixed3D [BorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.borderstyle.aspx) but this has the same problem:

[image: Form using 3DBorders that has a similar problem.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last moments of writing this question I had an epiphany. The dotted lines inside the SplitContainer are just guidelines and not a fixed margin. The location of the nested SplitContainer is 3, 3.

By manually setting the location to 0, 0 (the designer snaps to 3, 3) the grey on the left disappeared. I also had to enlarge it by 3 pixels to prevent a new border on the right.

Doing this to each nested SplitContainer solved my problem:
[Fixed form http://fr33dan.com/Fixed.png](http://fr33dan.com/Fixed.png)

Answer (score 0):

Give the splitcontainers different backcolors than their panels AND set the borderstyles of them all to None.

Comment: How does this answer the question, esp. while they already answered their own question?

Comment: Hi Gert. My solution does not need a border. I see your point, though.